# Need to show post summary in sidebar

Tags: excerpt

I need to show a summary of each post in the sidebar. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Add your summary in the excerpt field, loop through the posts and echo out the excerpt on each post

Comment: Please update your question to provide a narrowly scoped problem. Currently, it is not clear which part of the task you have a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is use - `excerpt()` else you can also use `wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' );`

In a `excerpt()`, You have to add content on excerpt in backend. While `wp_trim_words` will trim words from content.

In sidebar case you have to add shortcode into functions.php file which uses in sidebar widget(if you are using widgets).

```
function test_short(){
    ob_start();
    global $post;
    echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content($post->ID), 40, '...' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('test_short', 'test_short');
```